# Text annotation replacement for google's cloud vision in pytesseract or microsoft's cognitive services

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, python-tesseract, google-cloud-vision

I need an alternate for google's cloud vision code as below 
      
        `client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()
        with io.open(tempFile, 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
            image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
        response = client.text_detection(image=image)
        print(response.text_annotations)`

The output for the above code gives me the output of text labels and bounding coordinates as shown below

```
[locale: "en"description: "JANE CITIZEN\n10/04/1960\n10/04/2014\n3 THIRD ST\nADELAIDE 5000\n"bounding_poly {vertices {x: 107y: 134 }vertices { x: 684 y: 134}}]
```

I need to emulate the same output using pytesseract or microsoft's cognitive service or some other ocr tool

Comment: So? did you try to search on the web?

Comment: yea but no results

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-hand-text